# AppBar Title sticks to the left side of the screen

Tags: dart, flutter

Why does the Title stick to the left instead of leaving some space ?

This is the Scaffold code

> ```
> return new Scaffold(
>         appBar: new AppBar(title: const Text('Friendlychat')),);
> ```

[image: AppBar Title]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a regression in current flutter alpha release which is fixed in master - see this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12063)

For now, any of the workarounds mentioned in the answer by [aziza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3434970/aziza) can be used, but you will have to revert it when the new alpha is released

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways you can modify that:

You can wrap your `title` widget inside a `Padding` widget and use the `padding` property to indent the area on the left.

[image]

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Padding (child: new Text ("Friendly Chat"),
              padding:const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0) ),
        ),
    );
  }
```

Or you can add an empty `Container` in the `leading` property of your `AppBar`.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title:new Text ("Friendly Chat"),
          leading: new Container(),
        ),
    );
  }
```

If you want the title to be centered, set the property `centerTitle` in your `AppBar` to `true`

[image]

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title:new Text ("Friendly Chat"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a regression in current flutter alpha release which is fixed in master as pointed out by @aptik.Thanks